# What does getSandboxName() return for production orgs?

Tags: apex, sandbox

I'm checking the sandbox name so I can set outbound URLs properly on a button component. In my controller I have a method to get the sandbox name:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getCurrentSandboxName() {
    System.Domain domain = System.DomainParser.parse(URL.getOrgDomainUrl());
    return domain.getSandboxName();
}
```

I then use that value in my Aura component logic. For a development box like `company--boxname.my.salesforce.com`  the method returns `boxname`. What would it return in production (`company.my.salesforce.com`) where there is no such suffix on the subdomain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PRODUCTION it would return `null` as per documentation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Domain.htm#apex_System_Domain_getSandboxName

So when it returns `null` you can assume its PROD environment and append your production instance name and do your logic.

Comment: Thank you. I ran a general search for the method and Google failed me, returning only a bunch of discussions. I should've searched the docs directly.

Answer (score 5):

The quickest way to answer questions like these are to simply try it out.

Taking your snippet, extracting the important bits gets me

```java
System.Domain domain = System.DomainParser.parse(URL.getOrgDomainUrl());
system.debug(domain.getSandboxName());
```

And executing that as anomymous apex tells me that the result in a production org is `null`

Comment: Thanks, but I can't run against prod at my company.

Comment: @isherwood Do you have access to the developer console in your production org? If not, are you able to use the salesforce CLI to exectue `sfdx force:apex:execute -f /path/to/codeSnippet.txt`?

Comment: Nope. No access at all.

Comment: @isherwood That would certainly make developing ...a challenge. It might be worth it for you to sign up for a free developer edition org ( https://developer.salesforce.com/signup ) so that you would be able to run these non-data-affecting snippets with impunity.

Comment: It really hasn't been a problem. We have a clone of prod for QA, to which I have access. This is a rare case that I should've resolved by reading the docs. Thanks again.

Comment: heads up, I do believe the below returns null as well for scratch orgs: ```
System.Domain domain = System.DomainParser.parse(URL.getOrgDomainUrl());
system.debug(domain.getSandboxName());
```